# Turn category into column name

Tags: javascript

I am new at Javascript, and I am having problems with a list of dictionaries. I have an object such as this one:

```
0:{Year: "2007", expenditure: "314,448.7", category: "Exports"}
1:{Year: "2008", expenditure: "320,805.2", category: "Exports"}
2:{Year: "2007", expenditure: "314,448.7", category: "Imports"}
3:{Year: "2008", expenditure: "320,805.2", category: "Imports"}
```

and I would like to turn it into a new one with the values Exports and Imports as two different columns, with its correspondent expenditure below. Something like this:

```
0:{Year: "2007", Exports: "314,448.7", Imports: "314,448.7"}
1:{Year: "2008", Exports: "320,805.2", Imports: "320,805.2"}
```

Does anyone know how to do this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array#reduce` to accumulate object based on the `Year`. Then extract out all the values using `Object.values()`.

```js
const arr = [{Year: "2007", expenditure: "314,448.7", category: "Exports"},{Year: "2008", expenditure: "320,805.2", category: "Exports"}, {Year: "2007", expenditure: "314,448.7", category: "Imports"},{Year: "2008", expenditure: "320,805.2", category: "Imports"}],
    result = Object.values(arr.reduce((r, {Year, expenditure, category}) => {
      r[Year] = r[Year] || {Year};
      r[Year][category] = expenditure;
      return r;
    },{}));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the function `Arra.prototype.reduce` to accumulate according to the category.

```js
const arr = [{Year: "2007", expenditure: "314,448.7", category: "Exports"},{Year: "2008", expenditure: "320,805.2", category: "Exports"}, {Year: "2007", expenditure: "314,448.7", category: "Imports"},{Year: "2008", expenditure: "320,805.2", category: "Imports"}];
const result = Object.values(arr.reduce((a, e) => ((a[e.Year] || (a[e.Year] = { Year: e.Year }))[e.category] = e.expenditure, a), {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```